# Replace value using streams

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I have Spring Data Entity where I get paged result:

```
classItemsService.findAll(spec, pageable).map(classItemsMapper::toFullDTO);
```

Using MapStrict framework I filter the values returned from the API:

```
@Mapper(config = BaseMapperConfig.class)
public interface ClassItemsMapper {

    ClassItemsFullDTO toFullDTO(ClassItems classItems);
}
```

DTO:

```
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Builder(toBuilder = true)
public class ClassItemsFullDTO {
    ........
    private String productVideo;
    ........
}
```

The question is how I can replace second time the values returned from the DB and replacing then with some hardcoded value. For example I suppose that it should be like this:

```
Page<ClassItemsFullDTO> page = classItemsService.findAll(spec, pageable).map(classItemsMapper::toFullDTO).stream()
            .forEach(classItemsFullDTO -> classItemsFullDTO.setProductVideo("unsubscribed"));
```

Can you help me to fix the issue?

Now I get this issue:

```
Required type: Page <ClassItemsFullDTO>
Provided: void
```

Comment: Return type is `Page<ClassItems>` this is the entity.

Comment: Page is a Spring Interface from here: https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/domain/Page.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`Stream.forEach`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#forEach(java.util.function.Consumer)) method does not return anything, i.e. it returns `void`. So the assignment you are doing doesn't work with it. Remove `Page<ClassItemsFullDTO> page =`  and it will work.

If you need to keep a reference to the result, I suggest you don't use a `Stream`:

```
Page<ClassItemsFullDTO> page = classItemsService.findAll(spec, pageable)
        .map(classItemsMapper::toFullDTO);

page.forEach(dto -> dto.setProductVideo("unsubscribed"));
```

Comment: What about this: `Page<ClassItemsFullDTO> page = classItemsService.findAll(spec, pageable).map(classItemsMapper::toFullDTO);
        page.forEach(dto -> dto.setProductVideo("unsubscribed"));`